# Why do combinators look this way?

Tags: lambda-calculus, history, combinatory-logic

Out of curiosity, why do combinators look this way? For example, why is $K = \lambda x y \to x$ and why is it called $K$? Why is it not $\lambda x y f m \to f m x$? These are just arbitrary letters, I have no idea what this function does. Or why is $S = \lambda f g x \to f x (g x)$?

Who first discovered that combinators should look this way? Who named them?

Comment: The question seems a bit ambiguous to me. When you say "look this way", are you asking why the letters K and S were chosen for those particular functions? are you referring to the use of lambda calculus syntax in the definitions you gave? Are you asking about the specific meaning of the lambda calculus abstractions? The function $\lambda x y \to x$ essentially takes two arguments and evaluates to the first one; equivalently, it takes a single argument $x$ and evaluates to (a lambda which takes another argument and evaluates to $x$).

Answer (score 5):

The combinators $K$ and $S$ first appear in Moses Schönfinkel, [Über die Bausteine der mathematischen Logik](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Elangeh/test/1924%20-%20Schoenfinkel%20-%20Ueber%20die%20Bausteine%20der%20mathematischen%20Logik.pdf), though he calls them $C$ and $S$. He actually defines five combinators, $I,C,T,Z,S$, and then shows that they can all be expressed in terms of $C$ and $S$ alone.

The modern notation appears in Haskell Curry, [Grundlagen der Kombinatorischen Logik](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F2370619), in the order $I,K,B,C,S$ (which correspond to Schönfinkel's $I,C,Z,T,S$).

Schönfinkel calls $C$ the *constant function* (the German word starts with K), and $S$ the *fusion function*; perhaps the letter $S$ is in analogy to $Z$, the *composition function* (the German word starts with Z), defined by $Zxyz=x(yz)$. (To complete the picture, $I$ is the *identity function*, and $T$ is the *swap function* defined by $Txyz=xzy$.) Curry gives no explanation whatsoever for his choice of letters.

Comment: Let us just be thankful they didn't pick even more Greek letters.

Comment: Just stumbled over this, so let me throw my two cents in here: S could refer to "schmelzen", which literally means "to melt". T probably refers to "tauschen", which means "to swap". I believe it's all initials of respective words.

Answer (score 3):

This is so because $K$ and $S$ can be used to generate all other $\lambda$-terms (up to extensional equality), refer to [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis) for the details.